# Doubts regarding TAP in Wp7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have doubt regarding TAP of Windows Phone 7 application,

Im XAML i have declared as

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="65" x:Name="BalanceEnquiries"  >

            <my:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <my:GestureListener x:Name="BalanceEnquiriesEvent"  Tap="BalanceEnquiriesEvent_Tap"/>
            </my:GestureService.GestureListener></Grid>
```

and in my handler,I am using

```
private void BalanceEnquiriesEvent_Tap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
    {            
        Debug.WriteLine("Sender is "+sender);
        Debug.WriteLine("SenderEvent  is " + e.OriginalSource);
        Debug.WriteLine("Gesture Type" + e.GetType());}
```

and on click of the TAP Event,I am getting TAP Event getting called twice,Is this normal behaviour or some problem with layout.

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Comment: What are the senders? (what is written in the debug output)

Comment: It has been Tap that is written in gesture listener,on tap,that method is called twice

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh,

You are getting 2 events probably because you have something underneath the grid that is also getting the event.  If you check the sender you will see what other element is receiving the Tap.  You can either mark the event as handled or set the other element to IsHitTestVisible=false, which means it will not receive the event.